# Which words appear the most common in an indexed field?

Tags: solr

How could I query Solr for the most common indexed words? For example, given these fields for each document:

- There's a lady who's sure all the glitters is gold.
- Gold is worth more than silver.
- The lady is wearing a gold bracelet.

I would like Solr to return to me, in any format, the following output:

- gold (3)
- lady (2)
- the (2) // Being a stop word this isn't really necessary
- ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the luke request handler

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler

example:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke?fl=Your_Indexed_Field&numTerms=500`

Answer (score 5):

The [Terms Component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) seems well-suited to the task. Here is an article about [Self Updating Solr Stopwords](http://www.jason-palmer.com/2011/12/self-updating-solr-stopwords/) which uses the Terms Component to find the 1000 most common indexed words and add them to the Stopwords file.

Finding the 1000  indexed keywords (sorted by frequency descending):

```
http://url.to.solr/solr/terms?terms.fl=MY_FIELD&terms.limit=1000
```

Comment: Luke is faster, but doesn't allow the query to be filtered further. The TermsComponent can seek terms that match some regular expression, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the use case for Solr as far as I know but it can be done with faceting. No guarantees about performance though. Make sure your field is set to be tokenized properly, and then run a query as usual but with the following additional parameters at the end:

```
&facet=true&facet.field=yourfield
```

Replace `yourfield` with the name of the field you have your data stored in.

Comment: Thanks. The request times out for that, even on modestly-sized indexes. I should imagine that is one heavy query!

Comment: @dotancohen Yeah I thought it might. You're probably better off writing a simple program and hashing each word with a count.