# Solr Merge facet.field results into one facet result

Tags: solr, lucene, facet, faceted-search

I have the fields fieldA and fieldB (which are stored=true) and also a fieldSearch (which is stored=false and has copied values of fieldA and fieldB).

I need to get a faceted result on fieldSearch. I want to get one facet list with fieldA and fieldB merged (the counts are not important for me). Is this only possible if I store fieldSearch as well? In my scenario fieldSearch is a more complex type with filters.

I could create a field fieldAB with stored=true but it seems to me as a waste of space. Maybe someone could suggest a better approach.

To make it clear, let's say:

fieldA has values: banana, apple

fieldB has values: orange, apple

Instead of:

"facet_fields":{
"fieldA":[
    "banana":1,
    "apple":1],
"fieldB":[
    "orange":1,
    "apple":1,]}

I would like to have:

"facet_fields":{
"fieldAB":[
    "banana":x,
    "apple":x
    "orange:x]}

The count is not important.

Thanks

Comment: I think you might find this useful -http://stackoverflow.com/a/12350121

Comment: Thanks jay, but I'm not sure if that would help me. In my case I would need to retrieve the complete field, not only terms.

Comment: you can store your field as string, and then use the terms component.  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />   and the field will be <field name="fieldSearch_string" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/> . Since this field is just indexed, not stored, you will still save a lot of space.

Comment: Hi @jay, I understood it now. But still, I didn't find a way to use it with multiple fields. When I query for /terms?terms.fl=fieldA&terms.fl=fieldB, it gives me separated results, as with facets. And also I need to add a dynamic field like terms.fl=field* which I think it wouldn't accept.

I don't see any other way to it unless creating a new stored field and wasting more space.